# How to add a navbar from Bootstrap in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I can't add a Navbar in my project.
I would like to have my routes in my navbar, but I don't see how to do it

In my Navbar.js

```
import { Button, Nav, NavDropdown, Form, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
          <Form inline>
            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
            <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
          </Form>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

In my App.js

```
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/landing" component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

The page only loads but nothing happens. I followed the React-Bootstrap doc to the letter but nothing

Comment: Hi There. Consider making a reproducible demo using http://codesandbox.io/.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @jocewl : I've tried to solve the issue and I noticed that there is a conflict with component naming "Navbar" ,that is also a bootstrap buit in  component and your component have the same name too .

You can see my codesandbox .
link : https://codesandbox.io/s/navbarbootstrap-6d4k8?file=/src/NavBar.js

Let me know if it is what you're looking for , and like it if it solved your problem .

Thanks